# NameError: 'client' not defined (Discord Bot)

Tags: python

I have been having problems with a code saying

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Discord bot\bot.py", line 6, in 
@client.event
NameError: name 'client' is not defined

here is the code:

```
import discord
import os
import random
from discord.ext import commands

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online,
```

activity=discord.Game(';help'))
print('bot is ready.')

```
@client.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

    @client.command()
    async def unload(ctx, extension):
        client.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

@client.command(aliases=['8ball', 'test'])
async def eightball(ctx, *, question):
    responses = ['Maybe Yes',
                 'Maybe No',
                 'Probably No',
                 'Probably Yes',
                 'Never',
                 'Always',
                 'Yes',
                 'No',
                 'Try again later']
    await ctx.send(f'Question: {question}\nAnswer: {random.choice(responses)}')

@client.command()
async def clear(ctx, amount=5):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)

@client.command()
async def kick(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)

@client.command()
async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.ban(reason=reason)

@client.command()
async def unban(ctx, *, member):
    banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()
    member_name, member_discriminator = member.split('#')

    for ban_entry in banned_users:
        user = ban_entry.user

        if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
            await ctx.guild.unban(user)
            await ctx.send(f'Unbanned {user.mention}')
            return

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')

client.run('Token')
```

Comment: Can you please provide the part where you initialized the client variable? Otherwise we cant help you

Comment: As I already said you forgot to declare the client variable at the beginning.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+NameError+not+defined It's not like there's no explanation for the cause of the error out there, please take the time to do some research before asking yet another question. Also, extract a [mcve]. As a new user here, please take teh [tour] and read [ask] as well.

Answer (score 1):

I am asuming that you haven't defined the `client variable`, which is really important due the fact that your bot won't work without. With that beeing said you need to declare it and put it around your bot / client logic. Otherwise the bot / client won't work.

```
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game(';help'))
    print('Bot is ready.')

# Add more bot logic here, like commands or further events

client.run("INSERT_YOUR_TOKEN_HERE")
```